# And operator with 1 2 4 8 16-like enumaration

Tags: .net, vb.net, comparison, enumeration

I've been using this for long time. Now I want to know how it works. I have an example:

```
If e.State And DrawItemState.Selected Then
    'if e.state includes DrawItemState.Selected do something
End If
```

E.state has options like 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 and so on... Also e.State can include more then one of them. For example 4 + 32 which is 36 includes two states. I can check them with "and" operator. I am totaly aware of usage, yet I have no idea how it works. Also I am wondering is it more efficent then checking each condition with a "Select Case" block.

EDIT: I now understood the logic. How about efficency?

Comment: Have a look at [bitwise operations in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). That's what you're using there with the `And` operator.

Comment: I wonder if [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/58527/475820) would help you.  What you're asking about is a "Flags" Enum.

Comment: I've checked there before asking here. It doesn't give me the asnwer :(

Comment: If the two links provided don't give you want you want, perhaps you can clarify or extend your question to help us understand what you need?

Comment: My answer was to O. R. Mapper. I've checked your link just now. It tells how to use but not how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually conflates the logical and bitwise AND operators: there is an implicit cast, which throws a compiler error if you turn Option Strict On. It's more "correct" to only use the bitwise operator, as follows:

```
If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
```

Your question is a very good one. Visual Basic's AND operator is a bit confusing in this regard, and I believe many programmers would have the same confusion. I certainly did, back in the day :-)

As for efficiency compared to SELECT CASE, it depends whether you want to handle each flag on its own, or handle a pattern of flags.

It helps if you think of e.State as a panel of light switches that are each either on or off. SELECT CASE can be used to handle patterns of switches, but it can't be used to handle individual switches.

for example

```
CASE DrawItemState.Selected
```

will only trigger if e.State is ONLY .Selected. If e.State was .Selected plus .Focus, like this:

```
e.State = DrawItemState.Selected Or DrawItemState.Focus
```

then that CASE statement WOULD NOT trigger.

Comment: So please correct me if I am wrong. "e.State And DrawItemState.Selected" returns DrawItemState.Selected if e.State includes DrwItemState.Selected? I'm getting more confused :(

Comment: Okay. I manually did the operation(pen and paper :) ). Now everything is clear. How about efficency?

Comment: comment deleted - I'll add it to my answer

Comment: I think I am misunderstood. I have two options. One is using flags and this "And" operator. Other is for example keeping a boolean for each alternative and checking each by a if statement. So which is more efficent in this case?

Comment: It depends on whether the properties interact with each other. If you can process the .Selected property without knowing what the status of the other properties are, then I'd go with separate boolean variables. If, however, you have to take all properties into account before processing, then I'd go with flags.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Look at the numbers (1, 2, 4, 8...) in binary: `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000` etc. If you add them you get e.g. `1010` and "anding" them brings e.g.

```
  1010
& 1000
  ====
  1000
```

Since False = 0 and True = everything not 0 the if-statement works.

Comment: So it compares each bit of the integer and "And" operator favors 0 to 1. It really is intresting for a one of the highest level languages. Is it efficent?

Comment: it doesn't "favor" it. It compares both values bit by bit and if both values have a 1 at the same position, the ouptut value will have a 1 at that position (i.e 1010 & 1000 = 1000 and 1010 & 0101 = 0000 and 1010 & 0010 = 0010; look for bitwise operations: OR, AND, XOR). And it's usualy very efficient since it is a single processor operation.