# Adding Bytes with Option Strict On .NET

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation, byte

So Im trying to generate a Byte
`Dim test as Byte = 0`

Where I manipulate the Bits myself:

```
If ... Then test += 1
If ... Then test += 2
If ... Then test += 4
If ... Then test += 8
```

But with Option Strict On, the studio wants me to convert what im adding into Byte. This clearly is not the correct way, how can I do it correctly?

Comment: The issue is that the numeric constants 1, 2, 4, and 8 have type `Integer` unless you override.  Notwithstanding a comments I found when searching for this earlier, there doesn't appear to be a declaration suffix to identify a constant as a byte constant, so you need to wrap your integers in `CByte`.

Comment: But surely there is a smarter solution to do what im doing, as conversion seems so off on this purpose.

Comment: If you want to perform bitwise operations then use bitwise operators, not arithmetic operators, e.g. if you want to set third bit then you `Or` with 4. I suggest you do some research on bitwise operations.

Comment: @aludebe the "smarter" solution is to use a postfix on the constants to make them byte constants instead of integer constants, but in my experience such postfix doesn't exist in .NET 4.8.  It might exist in .NET 5.0 and onward, if so, I believe it's `UB`.  Re "conversion", I would expect the compiler to be smart enough to just emit a byte constant in IL, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: But `test or 1` has the same problem, 1 is an Integer and therefore the result is integer

Comment: I didn't say it would address that issue. I just said that you should use bitwise operators for bitwise operations.

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: It looks like you could improve the readability of the code by using an Enum, as described in [Combining Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517/combining-enums).

Comment: @aludebe If you use `Or` then setting the same flag twice is not a problem, but if you use `+` then it will reset that flag and set the next-highest in value, possibly cascading along. E.g. 12 Or 4 = 12, but 12 + 4 = 16.

Comment: Well my operation cant go past 15 or 1111. So I didnt consider that. On the other hand that would mean 0001 or 0001 = 0001. But it should be 0001 + 0001 = 0010. So its more the binary representation of numbers than actual bits. 1+1 should be 2

Comment: @aludebe That clarifies it a bit. The easy way would be to use an Integer instead of a Byte. I don't think it'll make any meaningful difference to the storage requirements or speed of the program.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewMorton: In the .NET world making use of the [`<Flags>` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0)  i.e. `<Flags()> Public Enum MyFlags As UInteger` makes coding bits far easier.